# D3.js with Total.js/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, contextify, total.js

I have been trying to use total.js with D3 to create a tree visualization. I am unable to download D3. I do :

```
npm install D3
```

I get:

```
npm ERR! contextify@0.1.8 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.8 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "d3"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/grantherman/Desktop/vendorTool/node_modules
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/grantherman/Desktop/vendorTool/node_modules/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I have tried to download contextify, but I get the same thing. I have successfully downloaded gyp, but it doesn't seem work if I try to download D3.js.

Comment: Probably not what is wrong but can you try `npm install d3` where the d is not uppercase? Not sure if npm is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download latest version of node.js (with node.js v0.12.0 everything works).

Answer (score 0):

**Update npm and use lowercase d3**

Update npm:

`npm install -g npm` may require `sudo`

Install d3:

`npm install d3`

Note: this will install `d3` in your current location to install `globally` use :

`sudo npm install d3 -g`